# FTP through Telnet: "CD FAILED!"

Tags: ftp, telnet

I am working with some cameras that can send images through FTP on a trigger event. I am having trouble setting up my FTP information. I am using telnet. Let me know if there is a better alternative.

Here is what I am doing:

1) Open a cmd prompt

2) `telnet <camera_ip_adress>`

3) Enter my username

4) `SET privilege`

5) `SET FTP SITE trigger HOST "<host_ip>"`

6) `SET FTP SITE trigger USERNAME "<username>"`

7) `SET FTP SITE trigger PASSWORD "<password>"`

8) `TEST TRIGGER INPUT`

9) `SHOW LOG MEMORY`

It shows me that it fails to change directory to the only folder in the root directory. It then tries to create the folder that with the name it tried to cd into and that fails as well.

This same thing works fine if I use all of the same information to just ftp into the computer without telnet. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Extra info:

The camera and the computer I am trying to ftp into are on different domains. My computer is on the same domain as the computer I am trying to ftp into.

Answer (score 0):

Telnet is its own protocol that negotiates (or at least attempts to) many different terminal features, such as echoing and window size.

Most Telnet clients have an option to disable "Telnet mode" which will stop this negotiation from happening.  You should try to do this.  It's probably injecting Telnet byte sequences into your FTP stream (it often starts with trying to enable Telnet's LINEMODE) which the FTP server doesn't understand.

I'm not really sure why people use a Telnet client to interact with arbitrary text-based protocols like SMTP and FTP.  You're probably better off using Netcat or something similar which won't inject byte sequences that the protocol you're really trying to interact with won't understand.

Comment: Thank you. That is very helpful. I have got Telnet working, but I'm not sure what I changed. I will give Netcat a look-see though if you recommend it.